# some hint for $y^2(y')+2xy'=y$ solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $$y^2(y')+2xy'=y$$
The solution goes like this:

We let $q=\frac{dx}{dy}$ and we differentiate
$$
2x=yq-y^2q^{-2}\\
2q=q-2yq^{-2}+(y+2y^2q^{-3})q'\\
q^3=-2y \text{ or }q=yq'
$$

I really don't understand the last part. How did we get $q^3=-2y \text{ or }q=yq'$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract $2q$ from the RHS and factor

$$ y(1 + 2yq^{-3})q' - (q+2yq^{-2}) = 0 $$

multiply through by $q^3$

$$ y(q^3 + 2y)q' - q(q^3+2y) = 0 $$
$$ (yq'-q)(q^3+2y) = 0 $$

Therefore $yq'-q = 0$ or $q^3+2y=0$

Comment: So it's basically simple arithmetic?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much.